# How to serialize an C# object to specific JSON

Tags: c#, json, json.net, json-serialization

I wanted to serialize C# object to JSON using Newtonsoft. I am able to serialize object with properties but didn't get expected JSON. I tried with layout property but didn't worked for me.

Expected JSON:

```
[{"EmployeeID":100,"EmployeeName":"Pradeep","Layout":{"fillColor":function(rowIndex){return'#5d5e5f';},"hLineColor":function(i,node){return'#446b8e';}}}]
```

Object Employee:

```
public class Employee
    {
        public int EmployeeID
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public string EmployeeName
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }
```

Console class:

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Employee> lstemployee = new List<Employee>
            {
                new Employee()
                {
                    EmployeeID = 100,
                    EmployeeName = "Pradeep",
                }
            };

            string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(lstemployee);
            Console.WriteLine(output);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

It works fine for EmployeeID and EmployeeName property. 
JSON I get:

```
[{"EmployeeID":100,"EmployeeName":"Pradeep"}]
```

Not able to get JSON for layout property. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You can't (well, you can but you shouldn't); JSON doesn't serialize functions, only data

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5373540/json-serializing-an-object-with-function-parameter

Comment: Where is `Layout`? What have you tried?

Comment: JSON represents the data not the behavior of class. You can not have functions as part of JSON structure.

Comment: `#5d5e5f` look like a data , possible just create a field and assign to that

Comment: Why you should serialize function ?

Answer (score 0):

Decorate your payload in below format. 
[
  {
    "EmployeeID": 100,
    "EmployeeName": "Pradeep",
    "Layout": {
      "fillColor": "function(rowIndex){return'#5d5e5f';}",
      "hLineColor": "function(i,node){return'#446b8e';}"
    }
  }
]